# Python Secret Santa Program - How To Achieve Higher Success Rate

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I decided to make a `Python` program that generates Secret Santa pairings based on hardcoded restrictions (ex. someone can't get his wife). My family members have busy schedules so it's hard to organize everyone to do a random hat drawing.

My program crashes seldomly because of unfortunate random pairings making remaining ones ILLEGAL (however, I catch them in the testing script portion). Think of it as a re-drawing in-person.

However, when my program is successful, I know that the pairings are correct without having to look at them myself because my program tests for validity. Tomorrow, I'm going to have to find a way to use the pairings to send everyone an email from my email account about who they have without me knowing who has who or who even has me.

The following is my full program code (all code is my own; I didn't look up any solutions online as I wanted the initial challenge for myself):

```
# Imports

import random
import copy
from random import shuffle

# Define Person Class

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.isAllowedToHaveSecretSanta = True
        self.isSecretSanta = False
        self.secretSanta = None

# ----- CONFIGURATION SCRIPT -----

# Initialize people objects

brother1 = Person("Brother1", "brother1@gmail.com")
me = Person("Me", "me@gmail.com")
brother2 = Person("Brother2", "brother2@gmail.com")
brother2Girlfriend = Person("Brother2Girlfriend", "brother2Girlfriend@gmail.com")
brother3 = Person("Brother3", "brother3@gmail.com")
brother3Girlfriend = Person("Brother3Girlfriend", "brother3Girlfriend@gmail.com")
brother4 = Person("Brother4", "brother4@gmail.com")
brother4Girlfriend = Person("Brother4Girlfriend", "brother4Girlfriend@gmail.com")
brother5 = Person("Brother5", "brother5@yahoo.com")
brother5Girlfriend = Person("Brother5Girlfriend", "brother5Girlfriend@gmail.com")
myDad = Person("MyDad", "myDad@gmail.com")
myDad.isAllowedToHaveSecretSanta = False
myMom = Person("MyMom", "myMom@gmail.com")
myMom.isAllowedToHaveSecretSanta = False
dadOfBrother4Girlfriend = Person("DadOfBrother4Girlfriend", "dadOfBrother4Girlfriend@gmail.com")
momOfBrother4Girlfriend = Person("MomOfBrother4Girlfriend", "momOfBrother4Girlfriend@gmail.com")

# Initialize list of people

personList = [brother1,
              me,
              brother2,
              brother2Girlfriend,
              brother3,
              brother3Girlfriend,
              brother4,
              brother4Girlfriend,
              brother5,
              brother5Girlfriend,
              myDad,
              myMom,
              dadOfBrother4Girlfriend,
              momOfBrother4Girlfriend]

# Initialize pairing restrictions mapping
# This is a simple dictionary where the key
# is a person and the value is a list of people who
# can't be that person's secret santa (they might
# be mom, girlfriend, boyfriend, or any reason)

restrictionsMapping = {brother1.name: [],
                       me.name: [], #anybody can be my secret santa
                       brother2.name: [brother2Girlfriend.name],
                       brother2Girlfriend.name: [brother2.name],
                       brother3.name: [brother3Girlfriend.name],
                       brother3Girlfriend.name: [brother3.name],
                       brother4.name: [brother4Girlfriend.name, dadOfBrother4Girlfriend.name, momOfBrother4Girlfriend.name],
                       brother4Girlfriend.name: [brother4.name, dadOfBrother4Girlfriend.name, momOfBrother4Girlfriend.name],
                       brother5.name: [brother5Girlfriend.name],
                       brother5Girlfriend.name: [brother5.name],
                       dadOfBrother4Girlfriend.name: [momOfBrother4Girlfriend.name, brother4Girlfriend.name, brother4.name],
                       momOfBrother4Girlfriend.name: [dadOfBrother4Girlfriend.name, brother4Girlfriend.name, brother4.name]}

# Define Secret Santa Class (Necessary for testing script)

class SecretSantaPairingProcess:

    # INITIALIZER

    def __init__(self, personList, restrictionsMapping):
        self.personList = copy.deepcopy(personList)
        self.restrictionsMapping = restrictionsMapping
        self.isValid = True

    # INSTANCE METHODS

    # Define a method that generates the list of eligible secret santas for a person
    def eligibleSecretSantasForPerson(self, thisPerson):
        # instantiate a list to return
        secretSantaOptions = []
        for thatPerson in self.personList:
            isEligible = True
            if thatPerson is thisPerson:
                isEligible = False
                # print("{0} CAN'T receive from {1} (can't receive from self)".format(thisPerson.name, thatPerson.name))
            if thatPerson.name in self.restrictionsMapping[thisPerson.name]:
                isEligible = False
                # print("{0} CAN'T receive from {1} (they're a couple)".format(thisPerson.name, thatPerson.name))
            if thatPerson.isSecretSanta is True:
                isEligible = False
                # print("{0} CAN'T receive from {1} ({1} is alrady a secret santa)".format(thisPerson.name, thatPerson.name))
            if isEligible is True:
                # print("{0} CAN receive from {1}".format(thisPerson.name, thatPerson.name))
                secretSantaOptions.append(thatPerson)
        # shuffle the options list we have so far
        shuffle(secretSantaOptions)
        # return this list as output
        return secretSantaOptions

    # Generate pairings
    def generatePairings(self):
        for thisPerson in self.personList:
            if thisPerson.isAllowedToHaveSecretSanta is True:
                # generate a temporary list of people who are eligible to be this person's secret santa
                eligibleSecretSantas = self.eligibleSecretSantasForPerson(thisPerson)
                # get a random person from this list
                thatPerson = random.choice(eligibleSecretSantas)
                # make that person this person's secret santa
                thisPerson.secretSanta = thatPerson
                thatPerson.isSecretSanta = True
                # print for debugging / testing
                # print("{0}'s secret santa is {1}.".format(thisPerson.name, thatPerson.name))

    # Validate pairings
    def validatePairings(self):
        for person in self.personList:
            if person.isAllowedToHaveSecretSanta is True:
                if person.isSecretSanta is False:
                        # print("ERROR - {0} is not a secret santa!".format(person.name))
                        self.isValid = False
                if person.secretSanta is None:
                    # print("ERROR - {0} does not have a secret santa!".format(person.name))
                    self.isValid = False
                if person.secretSanta is person:
                    self.isValid = False
                if person.secretSanta.name in self.restrictionsMapping[person.name]:
                    self.isValid = False
                for otherPerson in personList:
                    if (person is not otherPerson) and (person.secretSanta is otherPerson.secretSanta):
                        # print("ERROR - {0}'s secret santa is the same as {1}'s secret santa!".format(person.name, otherPerson.name))
                        self.isValid = False


# ----- EXECUTION SCRIPT -----

### Generate pairings
##
##secretSanta = SecretSantaPairingProcess(personList, restrictionsMapping)
##secretSanta.generatePairings()
##
### Validate results
##
##secretSanta.validatePairings()
##if secretSanta.isValid is True:
##    print("This is valid")
##else:
##    print("This is not valid")

# ----- TESTING SCRIPT -----

successes = 0
failures = 0
crashes = 0
successfulPersonLists = []

for i in range(1000):
    try:
        secretSanta = SecretSantaPairingProcess(personList, restrictionsMapping)
        secretSanta.generatePairings()
        secretSanta.validatePairings()
        if secretSanta.isValid is True:
            # print("This is valid")
            successes += 1
            successfulPersonLists.append(secretSanta.personList)
        else:
            # print("This is not valid")
            failures += 1
    except:
        crashes += 1
    print("Finished test {0}".format(i))

print("{0} successes".format(successes))
print("{0} failures".format(failures))
print("{0} crashes".format(crashes))

for successList in successfulPersonLists:
    print("----- SUCCESS LIST -----")
    for successPerson in successList:
        if successPerson.isAllowedToHaveSecretSanta is True:
            print("{0}'s secret santa is {1}".format(successPerson.name, successPerson.secretSanta.name))
        else:
            print("{0} has no secret santa".format(successPerson.name))
```

Forgive me for some redundant code, but I've been away from Python for a while and didn't have much time to relearn and re-research concepts.

At first, my program tests went along as follows: Mostly successful tests, 0 failures (illegal pairings), and seldom crashes (for the reason I mentioned above). However, that was BEFORE my family decided to add new rules to this year's Secret Santa. My mom could be someone's secret santa, and dad could be as well, but NO ONE could be either of their Secret Santas (since everybody gets them gifts every year anyway). My brother's wife's parents were also to be included, and there couldn't be any pairings among my brother, his wife, and his wife's parents.

When I put in these new restriction rules, my tests produced mostly failures and very few successes (since randomness usually led to 2 or 1 person not having a secret santa at the end of execution). See below:

[image]

The more restrictions that are placed in the Secret Santa process, the more complex the problem becomes to solve. I'm itching to improve this program's success rate. Is there a way? Are there rules (permutational or mathematically common) that I need to take into account when considering Secret Santa restrictions?

Comment: Since your restrictions are commutative you could put they in lists or sets (like `[b4, b4gf, b4gfm, b4gfd]`), pick a starting node and pick a person *not* in his set as his recipitant. This is your next node. If you complete a cycle you are done or you pick an new starting node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bipartite matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs).   You have two sets of nodes: one for givers and one for receivers. Each set has a node for each person in your family. There is an edge from a giver to the receiver if that pair is valid. Otherwise there is no edge. Then apply the bipartite matching algorithm.